# What is the cutoff Yashan date for Heckers flour?

Tags: food, yashan-chadash

What is the Yashan cutoff date for [Heckers flour](http://heckersceresota.com/)?

Comment: http://www.crcweb.org/yoshon%20guide%20prelim.%205774.pdf

Comment: esther Faham, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, to [enable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Comment: Question (assumption) beforehand - As far as I know, Heckers is a non-Jewish owned company. If you buy such flour, is there a requirement for it to be *yashan*?

Comment: @DanF As far as I know, only the Bach suggests the potential for being lenient when the grain was definitely owned by a non-Jew. Virtually all other authorities reject this leniency and the overwhelming majority consider it to still be a biblical prohibition.

Comment: @DanF In addition to Loewian's point, there is no reason the ownership of the milling company is relevant at all.

Comment: http://www.star-k.org/YoshonQuick-2015-3.pdf

Answer (score 3):

From Y. Herman's Guide to Chodosh (5776):

> Heckers white flour contains 100% winter wheat, as determined by
>   independent sources. Probable Chodosh date for malt is Dec 15, code
>   best by use date of June 15 17 (18 months after packing.)

Some people are not strict about malt, in which case the white flour is always Yoshon (since winter wheat in the United States is always planted well before Pesach yet doesn't hit store shelves till after).

With regard to Hecker's whole wheat flour:

> Heckers whole wheat flour Chodosh code Aug
>   2 16 (1 year after packing.)